# Translate epub files with Selenium using ebooklib

Tags: python, selenium, ebooklib

I want to translate epub files from Deepl site using Selenium. Actually I can also use request (I don't have API.) But when I open epub files using ebooklib the output is with HTML codes. So;

```
import ebooklib
from ebooklib import epub

book = epub.read_epub('test.epub')

for item in book.get_items():
    if item.get_type() == ebooklib.ITEM_DOCUMENT:
        text = item.get_content().decode('utf-8')
        item.content = text.encode('utf-8')
        print(text)
```

Output

```html
?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" epub:prefix="z3998: http://www.daisy.org/z3998/2012/vocab/structure/#" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head/>
  <body><div>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 888 1332" preserveaspectratio="none">
                <image width="888" height="1332" xlink:href="cover.jpeg"/>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" epub:prefix="z3998: http://www.daisy.org/z3998/2012/vocab/structure/#" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head/>
  <body><div id="_idContainer054" class="basic-text-frame">
            <div class="calibre1" id="calibre_pb_0"/><p class="heading" id="calibre_pb_1">How to Pick Quality Shares</p>
            <p class="subtitle">A three-step process for selecting profitable stocks</p>
            <p class="book-author">Phil Oakley</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" epub:prefix="z3998: http://www.daisy.org/z3998/2012/vocab/structure/#" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head/>
  <body><div class="basic-text-frame">
            <div class="calibre1" id="calibre_pb_0"/><p id="_idParaDest-1" class="heading1"><a id="_idTextAnchor000"/>Contents</p>
            <p class="toc"><a href="part0002.html#_idTextAnchor001">About the Author</a></p>
            <p class="toc"><a href="part0003.html#_idTextAnchor002">Preface</a></p>
            <p class="toc1"><a href="part0003.html#_idTextAnchor003">What this book covers</a></p>
            <p class="toc1"><a href="part0003.html#_idTextAnchor004">Who this book is for</a></p>
            <p class="toc1"><a href="part0003.html#_idTextAnchor005">How this book is structured</a></p>
            <p class="toc"><a href="part0004.html#_idTextAnchor006">Introduction</a></p>
            <p class="toc1"><a href="part0004.html#_idTextAnchor007">My approach to investing</a></p>
            <p class="toc"><a href="part0005.html#_idTextAnchor008">Part 1 – How To Find Quality Companies</a></p>
```

I want to somehow output them as raw text, then translate them with Selenium or request and save them as epub again. How can I do it?

If I try to translate it with the text variable, it may not translate there are HTML codes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried BeautifulSoup? Also nltk to reach sentence level?

```
for item in book.get_items():
    if item.get_type() == ebooklib.ITEM_DOCUMENT:
        text = BeautifulSoup(item.content, 'lxml').get_text()
        print(text)
        # divide into paragraphs and sentences
        paragraphs = text.split('\n')
        for paragraph in paragraphs:
            sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(paragraph)
            print(sentence)
```